# Conditional invocation of a method in Scala

Tags: scala, scalaz

I've found this pattern quite a few times in my code:

```
  if (doIt)
    object.callAMethod
  else
    object
```

I'm wondering if there could be a syntactically more pleasing way to write the code above, especially to avoid the repetition of the `object` variable. Something like:

```
   // using the Scalaz "pipe" operator
   // and "pimping" f: T => T with a `when` method
   object |> (_.callAMethod).when(doIt)
```

Unfortunately the line above fails because the type inference requires a parameter type for `(_.callAMethod)`.

My best approach for now is this:

```
    implicit def doItOptionally[T](t: =>T) = new DoItOptionally(t)
    class DoItOptionally[T](t: =>T) {
      def ?>(f: T => T)(implicit doIt: Boolean = true) = 
        if (doIt) f(t) else t
    } 

    implicit val doIt = true
    object ?> (_.callAMethod)
```

Not great because I have to declare an `implicit val` but this pays off if there are several chained calls:

```
     object ?> (_.callAMethod) ?> (_.callAnotherMethod)
```

Does anyone have a better idea? Am I missing some Scalaz magic here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
class When[A](a: A) {
  def when(f: A => Boolean)(g: A => A) = if (f(a)) g(a) else a
}
implicit def whenever[A](a: A) = new When(a)
```

Example:

```
scala> "fish".when(_.length<5)(_.toUpperCase)
res2: java.lang.String = FISH
```

Comment: I didn't think of inverting the condition and the function, thanks!

Comment: I also notice that a noun goes better here than an operator because the `.` needs to be used after `"fish"`.

Answer (score 4):

I can't comment on your answer @Rex Kerr but a more concise way to do that would be:

```
implicit class When[A](a: A) {
  def when(f: A => Boolean)(g: A => A) = if (f(a)) g(a) else a
}
```

Just putting the `implicit` before the class allows you to omit the implicit function entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If you represent your `callAMethod` as an endomorphism then you can use the monoid functionality. Something like:

```
object |> valueOrZero(doIt, Endo(_.callAMethod))
```

(might need a type parameter on the `Endo`)